# How persisted specific data in localStorage in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, local-storage, vuetify.js

All the data present in my store is persisted in the localStorage but I would like to persist only my user, the user is stored in a nuxt.js store.

Here is my `store/login.js`

```js
export const state = () => ({
    user: ''
})

export const mutations = {
    setUser(state, newUser) {
        state.user = newUser;
    }
}

export const getters = {
    getUser(state) {
        return state.user
    }
}
```

And I am using `vuex-persist` plugin to persist the data.
Here is my `plugin/vuex-persist` :

```js
import VuexPersistence from 'vuex-persist';

export default ({ store }) => {
  new VuexPersistence({
    key: 'vuex',
    storage: window.localStorage,
  }).plugin(store);
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

From the [vuex-persist documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist#detailed):

```
const vuexCookie = new VuexPersistence<State, Payload>({
  restoreState: (key, storage) => Cookies.getJSON(key),
  saveState: (key, state, storage) =>
    Cookies.set(key, state, {
      expires: 3
    }),
  modules: ['user'], //only save user module
  filter: (mutation) => mutation.type == 'logIn' || mutation.type == 'logOut'
})
```

The options object has a "modules" key that expects a string[] value, with the names of the modules you DO want to serialize.

```
Constructor param: modules
Value type: string[]
Description: List of modules you want to persist. (Do not write your own reducer if you want to use this)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I had seen this on the documentation but I can't get it to work with my code

Comment: If you're sure you're using it right and you're sure it's the library malfunctioning you can file an Issue on the github repo for the project.

Comment: No it's me who must make it work badly, but in the documentation its `module: ['user']` comes from an import so how can I import my user from my store?